# writing file not showing what i want it to

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have. I want the gross, firstwinner, secondwinner, thirdwinner, and net to show, but this is what I get. What am I doing wrong?

```
<function gross at 0x103f12c10><function firstwinner at 0x103f12dc0><function secondwinner at 0x103f12e50><function thirdwinner at 0x103f12ee0><function net at 0x103f1e040>


    def directions():
        print("Thank you for entering our annual raffle contest.")
        print("I'm going to explain how the contest works.")
        print("You already paid your entry fee to get in, so now you just need your raffle ticket.")
        print("There will be 3 winners.")
        print("The first place winner receives the most, of course.")
        print("The second place winner receives half of that.")
        print("The third place winner receives half of what the second place winner gets.")
        print("Good luck!!")


    def entryfee ():
        file = open('entry_fee.txt')
        line = file.read()

    x = "contestants"
    y = "entryfee"

    def contestants():
        number = input("How many people entered the contest?")
        return number

    def entryfee(x, y):
        return x**y

    def gross(x, y):
        return contestants(x, y) * entryfee(x, y)

    def firstwinner():
        name1 = input("First place winner's name?")
        return name1

    def secondwinner():
        name2 = input("Second place winner's name?")
        return name2

    def thirdwinner():
        name3 = input("Third place winner's name?")
        return name3

    def prize():
        prize = input("How much did the first place winner receive?")
        return prize    

    def net():
        sum = gross - (prize + (prize*.5) + (prize*.25))


    myfile = open('results.txt', 'w')
    myfile.write(str(gross))
    myfile.write(str(firstwinner))
    myfile.write(str(secondwinner))
    myfile.write(str(thirdwinner))
    myfile.write(str(net))
    myfile.close()

    directions()
    contestants()
    firstwinner()
    secondwinner()
    thirdwinner()
    prize()
```

This is what I have. I want the gross, firstwinner, secondwinner, thirdwinner, and net to show, but this is what I get. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're printing the functions themselves, rather than calling them and printing the results.  Then, after printing the function objects, you call them all and discard the results.  You'd also be better off using `print` rather than `write`.  E.g. `print(str(gross()), file=myfile)`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you try to achieve here.

First you define x and y as String (word), then open your file "Result.txt" and write in it.

Many problems appear here. You want to write str(gross) but I see gross is a function. It takes two arguments as input, x and y, that should be numbers (Int, Float or Double). Calling str(gross) should not do anything because you do not give argument to the function gross. You should write str(gross(x, y)). A new problem will appear here because x and y are define in your code as String, thus you can't compute value with this, you need numbers. 
Moreover, you try to call contestants in gross providing x and y to contestants but when you declare def contestants you do not give argument as parameter. It should be def contestants(x, y).

Next, you try to write again in your file before calling the functions. Typing str(fristwinner) does not call the function firsrwinner, you should write str(firstwinner()). The parentheses are very importantes.

Finally, your are calling all of your function at the end. Why don't you call them before writing in your file?